# ExpressJS, recognize view engin in module structure

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express

I created files:

app.coffee

```
express  = require('express')
routes   = require('./config/routes')
app      = express.createServer();

require('./config/environment')(app)
require('./config/routes')(app)

app.listen(3000);
```

config/environment.coffee

```
module.exports = (app) ->
  app.configure = () ->
    # set view path, template engine and defsult layout
    app.set 'view', __dirname + '/views'
    app.set 'view engine', 'jade'
    app.use(app.router)
```

config/routes.coffee

```
site = require('../controllers/site.js')
module.exports = (app) ->
  app.get '/', site.index
```

controllers/site.coffee

```
exports.index = (req, res) ->
  res.render 'main.jade', {title: 'New Article'}
```

Problem is in site.coffee file, becouse when I don't write extension like 'jade' ExpressJS engin trying open files with 'undefined' extension. How Can I remember view engine from environment file ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the line

```
app.set 'view engine', 'jade'
```

As the [Express docs](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) say, all it does is allow you to omit the `.jade` extension, e.g.

```
res.render 'main', {title: 'New Article'}
```

Your problem is, I believe, the line

```
app.set 'view', __dirname + '/views'
```

which you're running from `config/environment.coffee`. `__dirname` is file-specific, so you've set your views directory to `config/views`—probably not what you intended. Try just omitting that line; the default is `path.join process.cwd(), 'views'`, which I'm guessing is what you actually want.

Also, although you have a comment about setting the "default layout," I don't see one. So if you continue to have problems, you may want to try

```
res.render 'main.jade', {layout: false}
```